# Oracle Deadlock

Tags: database, oracle, deadlock

Recently I am seeing some deadlock randomly once or twice a day, so I looked at the code & we are putting the code in a single transaction.  At the same time I want to increase the ini_trans to 5 on Oracle so it can handle concurrent access.  The application is using "app_user" schema which calls "app_admin" schema (app_admin owns the table) & the database is concurrently accessed by multiple application instances at the same time. Should I increase the ini_trans on app_user or app_admin or both?.  Thanks.

Comment: 1) What exactly is your error message?  2) Have you looked at the trace file generated for the deadlock?  It will tell you what objects are involved.  3) Are you sure it's not caused by your code asking for resources in an inconsistent order?  I've seen lots of deadlocks, but never because some Oracle setting was too low.

Comment: 1. SQL Error: 60, SQLState: 61000
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update 2. Yes, there was an object involved, I fixed the code to handle everything in a single transaction just to make sure it is not causing the application. 3. There was no code change in that area for a while & all of sudden it started happening after adding few constraints on the database which enforces the data integrity.  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of constraints did you add?  Did you add any new indexes?  It's possible for the exact same query to create a deadlock if the query plan changes between executions.  For example, one session uses a full table scan and update the rows in the order A B.  And another session uses an index and updates the rows in the order B A.

Comment: Added foreign key constraints with delete cascade. No new indexes.  The EJB entitymanager uses hibernate to persist, I noticed Insert & update are performed back & forth on a table.  So I am putting the entire code in a single transaction.

Comment: A single transaction won't necessarily help you.  You need to find the rows affected, and then look at the SQL statements in both sessions to see how resources were acquired in different orders.

Comment: The same code was working fine before these DB constraints.  We never had this deadlock problem.  Anyway I rolled out a new version, I will know when it gets to production.  I will update this thread once I hear from the production team.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:3932525800346405986) described the possible causes of the problem. The following advice helped me: "*index the foreign key and the deadlock disappears*". Check out the foreign keys, referenced to your table, and try to index them.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would have been MAXTRANS that you'd want to consider modifying, not INITRANS, but in 10.2 upwards it is deprecated, and a value of 255 is used by default.

Got any bitmap indexes? They're good for causing contention.

Comment: There is no bitmap indexes, just regular indexes only.  I was reading this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_initrans.htm page & thought I have to increase the INITRANS.  I am using Oracle 10g, when I checked the query ini_trans=1 & max_trans=255. 1. Which one should i change ini_trans or max_trans? and 2. What is the best values for these two?.  Thanks.

Comment: How many users do you think will be concurrently accessing a block in the table?

Comment: The concurrency is handled by JBOSS Container Managed Persistence, may be roughly we have like 50 or 100 JMS instances.  All instances will be using the same user "app_user" schema to access the app_admin tables.

Comment: Can some one please help me?...Should I change the MAXTRANS on app_admin or app_user schema?

Comment: What value does it have at the moment? 255 is the 10g default but if you upgraded from a lower version then it might be less. If so then just set it to 255, and that will cover 255 simultaneous accesses to the same table block.

Comment: I think it is 255 currently, should I change the MAXTRANS to may be 300 (just to be safe) since I don't know how many JMS instances we have in production currently.